# Bring Images in BIN form in mySQL database into Android App

Tags: android, mysql, image

I researched and found allot of similar questions. Two questions

1- [with all the PHP and mySQL BLOB] side done and working. How can I upload a drawable / image into the database ? I'm trying

```
public void AddRecord(String spin_cb, String statusinput_cb, String comment_cb, Drawable image_cb) {

        try {
            //SQLiteDatabase db = _dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); THIS IS THE LOCAL DATABASE LOGIC DISABLED
            /*ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Column_itemcatagory,itemcatagory);
            values.put(Column_itemtype,itemtype);
            values.put(Column_itemdesc, itemdesc);
            values.put(Column_contact, contact);
            values.put(Column_reward, reward);

            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);*/

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cb_spin", spin_cb));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cb_status", statusinput_cb));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cb_rate", comment_cb));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cb_image", image_cb.toString()));


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.bidland.ie/carbook/Insert.php");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(tag,"AddRecord Exception [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
        } 
    }
```

But namesvaluepair does not take in Drawable ?

2- The records that I created on mySQL, how can I read them back, JSON is working perfectly for strings, but how to get the images back ?

Answer (score 0):

About uploading, you have multiple tutorials on the web, like [this one](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/) or [this one](http://flo.dauran.com/194-android-uploader-une-image-sur-une-serveur-web/).

About getting back your images, I think Blobs are stored as byte arrays in SQLite, so you'll have to get your inputstream, convert it to a byte array and put it in the `ContentValues`. IOUtils is from Apach commons-io [lib](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

From the last line of your code :

```
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("cb_image", bytes);
...
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values);
```

Note that this **MUST BE DONE** in an AsynTask, as network loading and database writing must be done in background.